# Make double digits on stopwatch

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building an Angular 9 app. In this app I got a stopwatch component that counts up. This works perfectly fine but I need it to be double digits.

Right now the output is:

```
0:0:9
```

I need it to be

```
00:00:09
```

This is the method that takes care of the output.

```
timeDifference() {
    const currentTime = moment().valueOf();
    const startTime = moment(this.form.get('starts_at').value).valueOf();
    const difference = currentTime - startTime;
    let hours = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    hours = (hours < 10) ? 0 + hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? 0 + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? 0 + seconds : seconds;
    this.pastTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need quotation marks in your concatenation. like `hours = (hours < 10) ? '0' + hours : hours;`

Comment: You can convert the number to a string and add padding to it with zeros.`(7).toString().padStart(2 , "00")`

Answer (score 2):

**Your code** with Zero concatenated as string.

```js
let hours = 9;
let minutes = 6;
let seconds = 30;
hours = (hours < 10) ? '0' + hours : hours;
minutes = (minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
console.log(hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
```

**[padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)** as mentioned by @mark-baijens

```js
let hours = 9;
let minutes = 6;
let seconds = 30;
console.log(hours.toString().padStart(2, '00') + ':' + minutes.toString().padStart(2, '00') + ':' + seconds.toString().padStart(2, '00'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using moment why reinvent the wheel? You can just use moment's "format()" function to get the desired output. Or even using the native Date object's "toLocaleTimeString".

You can see both in action in this snippet:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById("localeDiv").innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("momentDiv").innerHTML = moment().format("HH:mm:ss");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<h4>With Date.toLocaleTimeString()</h4>
<div id="localeDiv"></div>

<h4>With moment</h4>
<div id="momentDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calculating a string, you could directly format the value.

```
this.pastTime = `${hours < 10 ? '0' : ''}${hours}:${minutes < 10 ? '0' : ''}${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${seconds}:`
```

Alternatively, a more cleaner approach would be to store hours, minutes and seconds in three separate fields accessible from the template and format it in the template itself via custom pipe. Assuming you have the three variables available in the template, you could write a pipe like following:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'doubledigit'
})
export class DoubleDigitPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number, ...args: unknown[]): string {
    return `${value < 10 ? '0' : ''}${value}`;
  }

}
```

and in the template where you want to show it

```
{{ hours | doubledigit }}:{{ minutes | doubledigit }}:{{ seconds | doubledigit }}
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
let hours = 2;
let minutes = 3;
let seconds = 20;
function n(n){
    return n > 9 ? "" + n: "0" + n;
}
console.log(n(hours) + ':' + n(minutes) + ':' + n(seconds));
```